# New element animation in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I am using ng-repeat with some style and I am going to add new items to the array. This is what I did:

```js
// Code goes here 

var _app = angular.module("userApp", [])
_app.controller("usrController", function($scope) {
  $scope.usrList = [];
  $scope.adduser = function() {
    console.log($scope.newUsr)
    $scope.usrList.push({
      name: $scope.newUsr
    })
  }
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.listItem {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="userApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.2" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="usrController">
    <input ng-model="newUsr">
    <button ng-click="adduser()">Adduser</button>
    <ul>
      <li class="listItem" ng-repeat="usr in usrList">{{usr.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And I am going to add stackoverflow effect for new elements added. When I add new element, it should fade or any other animation effect like background-color change.

- How can I do this?
- I do this with css3 only?
- Is there any way to add same effect if the already rendered element
  is changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use use [`ngAnimate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module and set up classes for [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations).

First, include the module in the project (remember to include corresponding script tag also):

```
angular.module("userApp", ['ngAnimate'])
```

Then define desired transitions/animations. For example:

```
.listItem.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.listItem.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2QuyxMt4kiYkKeCoMGCL?p=preview

Comment: How would you do that if you were adding a new item at the top with a fade in?