# How to add background color to the newly added row angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I would like to know in the below example how can i add the back ground color to the newly added row. On adding the new row the scroll is coming down but how to highlight it by adding the background color to the row. Any help would be great. Here is fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cpfx07qq/

```
html - 
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add()" scroll-bottom="bottom">Add</button>
    <ul id="bottom">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this may help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30322961/6582942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add()" scroll-bottom="bottom">Add</button>
    <ul id="bottom">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-class="{last: $last && isNew }">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in `controller`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isNew = false;
    $scope.list = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5"];
    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.isNew = true;
        $scope.list.push("new item");
    }
}
```

in `css`:

```
.last {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive("scrollBottom", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var $id= $("#" + attr.scrollBottom);
            $(element).on("click", function(){
                $id.scrollTop($id[0].scrollHeight);
            });
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["item 1", "item 2","item 3","item 4","item 5"];
    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.list.push("new item");
    }
}
```

```css
ul {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
li:last-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add()" scroll-bottom="bottom">Add</button>
    <ul id="bottom">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```